# Python function: use timestamp to look for events in other data with a similar timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

I'm facing a problem with multiple dataframes that each consist of a DatetimeIndex (e.g. 2016-04-01 00:00:54) and a column containing numeric values. I am looking to compare the value of df-a with the values of df-b at around the timestamp found in df-a (ideally the values of df-b immediately before and after the timestamp in df-a). The problem is that the timestamps differ from dataframe to dataframe, so I cannot use a simple regex search.

At the end I would like to have a new dataframe df-new, which contains 3columns (+their respective DatetimeIndex): orginal value of df-a, df-b value before, df-b value after;

Here are some example dataframes:

1. df-a:

```
TS_TIMESTAMP             TREND_VALUE            
2019-04-03 18:48:10.970     1        
2019-04-04 16:49:23.320     1          
2019-04-05 13:19:33.550     1
```

2. df-b:

```
TS_TIMESTAMP             TREND_VALUE 
2019-04-03 16:40:23.320     18.6
2019-04-03 18:50:10.970     9.34                    
2019-04-03 18:47:10.970     19.34        
2019-04-04 16:45:23.320     18.8
2019-04-04 16:52:23.320     8.84 
2019-04-04 16:53:23.320     8.5        
2019-04-05 13:11:33.550     18.48
2019-04-05 13:15:33.550     18.9
2019-04-05 13:23:33.550     8.4
2019-04-05 13:30:33.550     8.6
```

An expected output would look like this:

```
TS_TIMESTAMP            TREND_VALUE   Value_before   Value_after
2019-04-05 13:15:33.550   NaN         18.9           NaN 
2019-04-05 13:19:33.550   1           NaN            NaN
2019-04-05 13:23:33.550   NaN         NaN            8.6
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you show us your expected output?

Comment: Sure, I added simpler examples and a sample df-new